# Condition statement not clear t->item

Tags: conditional-statements

I have got a got a code to search through a binary search tree, and i can't understand the t->item in the if conditions.

```
search(item, t) {  

     if (t == NULL) // t is an empty tree      
       {item is not present  in tree, t, and terminate search }  

     else if (item == t->item) 
             {item is present in tree, t, and terminate search}

            else if (item < t->item) 
                    {search in left subtree (i.e. t->left) recursively}

                  else             
                    {search in right subtree (i.e. t->right) recursively}
  }
```

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

item == t->item means "if item is the root of the tree". Otherwise, you'll look whether if it's greater or less than the root to see if you're continuing to search in the left or in the right subtree.